# Android - Kotlin - How can I create an alert dialog when a view is clicked on a recycler view item?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I'm using the same code outside of the recycler view adapter and it works fine. But here nothing happens when I click on the view.

```
holder.edit.setOnClickListener {
    if(context is MainActivity){
        val mDialog = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.add_ip_dialog, null)
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(mDialog).setTitle("New Product Information")
        val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()
        mDialog.save_button_dialog.setOnClickListener {
            mAlertDialog.dismiss()
        }
        mDialog.cancel_button_dialog.setOnClickListener {
            mAlertDialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the "this" to "context" but nothing changed.

Comment: In what activity are you using the recycler view?

Answer (score 0):

I used a button in a fragment and I use it like this.

```
imgBack.setOnClickListener {

        val eBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        eBuilder.setTitle("Discard Note")
        eBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning)
        eBuilder.setMessage("Note is not Saved. Are you sure you want to discard note?")
        eBuilder.setPositiveButton("Discard", fun(_: DialogInterface, _: Int) {
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()

        })

        eBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){
                _, _ -> eBuilder.setCancelable(true)
        }

        eBuilder.create()
        eBuilder.show()


    }
```

this should help and give a good example

Comment: I'm using the recycler view in the main activity.

Comment: In my honest opinion you should keep the Main Activity with as little code possible. This will greatly improve performance. I would honestly move the recycle view to a fragment and just call the fragment from main view.

Comment: @AbdurrahmanAlbakkar also i used this on a back button, this code can be used as an example but it does create the alert dialog with button functionality

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the if statement from the code.

Comment: @AbdurrahmanAlbakkar its great that it worked. If you used my solution and it worked you can click the answer worked. I would appreciate it